# Migrar datos de una tabla en Excel a Postgres desde JAVA

Tags: java, postgresql, excel

Estoy queriendo migrar los registros de una tabla excel hacia una bd postgres. El código funciona casi completamente, pero en vez de guardarme todos los registros de forma independiente, me guarda solo el primer registro durante repetidas ocasiones.

```
int contador = 1;       

        try {

            Workbook archivo = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File(archivoDestino));

            for (int hojas = 0; hojas < archivo.getNumberOfSheets(); hojas++) {

                Sheet hoja = archivo.getSheet(hojas);
                int numColumnas = hoja.getColumns();
                int numFilas = hoja.getRows();

                String dato;

                for (int fila = 1; fila < numFilas; fila++) {

                    for (int columna = 0; columna < numColumnas; columna++) {

                        dato = hoja.getCell(columna, fila).getContents();

                        switch(contador) {

                            case 1:
                                numero = dato;                                      
                                contador++;
                                break;                                                                                          

                            case 2:
                                nombre_1 = dato;
                                contador++;
                                break;

                            case 3:
                                tiempo = dato;
                                contador++;
                                break;

                            case 4:
                                estado = dato;
                                contador++;
                                break;

                            case 5:
                                dispositivo = dato;
                                contador++;
                                break;

                            case 6:
                                tipo_registro = dato;
                                contador++;
                                break;

                        }

                    }                                   

                    String sql = "insert into funcionarios_bio (numero, nombre, tiempo, estado, dispositivo, tipo_registro)"
                            + " values (?,?,?,?,?,?)";

                        PreparedStatement preparada = conexion.prepareStatement(sql);

                        preparada.setString(1, numero);
                        preparada.setString(2, nombre_1);
                        preparada.setString(3, tiempo);
                        preparada.setString(4, estado);
                        preparada.setString(5, dispositivo);
                        preparada.setString(6, tipo_registro);

                        preparada.executeUpdate();


                }

            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {

            ex.printStackTrace();

        }
```

Sé que el error es pequeño, pero no logro detectarlo. Esta es la imagen de la tabla en excel que estoy probando...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y el resultado del código:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He probado multiples opciones pero quizá me complico solo y no encuentro un error tan simple, pero en este caso he decidido pedir ayuda... XD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mete el insert dentro del for, porque en realidad solo te esta insertando el último dato que termina en el for.

algo así

```
int contador = 1;       

        try {

            Workbook archivo = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File(archivoDestino));

            for (int hojas = 0; hojas < archivo.getNumberOfSheets(); hojas++) {

                Sheet hoja = archivo.getSheet(hojas);
                int numColumnas = hoja.getColumns();
                int numFilas = hoja.getRows();

                String dato;

                for (int fila = 1; fila < numFilas; fila++) {

                    for (int columna = 0; columna < numColumnas; columna++) {

                        dato = hoja.getCell(columna, fila).getContents();

                        switch(contador) {

                            case 1:
                                numero = dato;                                      
                                contador++;
                                break;                                                                                          

                            case 2:
                                nombre_1 = dato;
                                contador++;
                                break;

                            case 3:
                                tiempo = dato;
                                contador++;
                                break;

                            case 4:
                                estado = dato;
                                contador++;
                                break;

                            case 5:
                                dispositivo = dato;
                                contador++;
                                break;

                            case 6:
                                tipo_registro = dato;
                                contador++;
                                break;

                        }

                    String sql = "insert into funcionarios_bio (numero, nombre, tiempo, estado, dispositivo, tipo_registro)"
                            + " values (?,?,?,?,?,?)";

                        PreparedStatement preparada = conexion.prepareStatement(sql);

                        preparada.setString(1, numero);
                        preparada.setString(2, nombre_1);
                        preparada.setString(3, tiempo);
                        preparada.setString(4, estado);
                        preparada.setString(5, dispositivo);
                        preparada.setString(6, tipo_registro);

                        preparada.executeUpdate();


                    }                                   


                }

            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {

            ex.printStackTrace();

        }
```